# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property with one to many

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to create a one to many relationship using Spring Boot and Hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cluster")
public class Cluster{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String project;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "testclusters", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Record> records;
```

My second entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Record")
public class Record{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String summary;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Cluster cluster;
```

So I want to save the id of the cluster to the record table.

But I keep getting the error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.clusters.Model.Record.Cluster in com.example.clusters.Model.Cluster.record`

Comment: There is no `testclusters` property on `record.

Comment: @M.Deinum Stupid typo! It works now